# Problems with boost log, version 1.59

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

The following code works as expected with boost 1.57:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

struct Foo
{
    int d=1;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Foo& foo)
{
    out << "Foo: " << foo.d;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << Foo();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

with boost 1.59 the same code fails. The first gcc error message is:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are
>   ‘boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_record_ostream’ and ‘Foo’)

Neither the documentation nor the release notes document what needs to be changed.

Comment: Live version: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Xn1hDoe7Zg7cynRX Looks like `enable_if_formatting_ostream` is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Live version](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Xn1hDoe7Zg7cynRX)
Looks like problem is in `enable_if_formatting_ostream` struct. It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/boostorg/log/commit/3d5d5e31d09a776374c2d38371ab93e554704bb7). And looks like

```
template< typename StreamT, typename R >
struct enable_if_formatting_ostream {};
template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT, typename AllocatorT, typename R >
struct enable_if_formatting_ostream< basic_formatting_ostream< CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT >, R > { typedef R type; };
```

And now `operator <<` is

```
template< typename StreamT, typename T >
inline typename boost::log::aux::enable_if_formatting_ostream< StreamT, StreamT& >::type
operator<< (StreamT& strm, T const& value)
```

Before it was

```
template< typename CharT, typename TraitsT, typename AllocatorT, typename T >
inline basic_formatting_ostream< CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT >&
operator<< (basic_formatting_ostream< CharT, TraitsT, AllocatorT >& strm, T const& value)
```

and since `record_ostream` is derived from `formatting_ostream` compiler can find overload, but now not, since SFINAE is used and struct will have `type` typedef only when `formatting_ostream` is used. And [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kIE3TMi4hVcoLVw0) can be workaround for this case.

Comment: After a look at the boost trac, this bug is recorded and fixed: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11549

Comment: how on earth did this get through regression testing?